# Tempo.js add new items into nested template

Tags: javascript, tempo

I use tempo.js which is fantastic tool, BUT.
I have a rendered template that contains nested templates.
For example: posts that has comments (just like as facebook).

Sometime user wants to add a new comment.
How can I refresh/rerender JUST the relevant nested templates (comments under one post) inside in one row?
Is it possible somehow?

Thank you for your answers.